# Mediaplayer error (-38,0) , stop called in state 4

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The result is that the first 2 songs are played well, but the others aren't played and it arrive to the last song without having played almost nothing!

Code to play the stream (it works):

```
    private void PlayStream(String url)
{
    try 
    {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        //  TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(Canzone.this);

    try 
    {
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               

    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setMax(duration);

    new Thread(this).start();
}
```

SPECIFICATION OF SETONCOMPLETELISTENER:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
        {
            i++;

            if(i<10)
            {   
                classifica.setText("Canzoni riprodotte: "+String.valueOf(i+1)+"/10 \nPunteggio: "+punteggio);

                mp.stop();  
                Log.d("MPLAY", "MP Stopped");

                mp.reset();
                Log.d("MPLAY", "MP Reset");

                PlayStream(dieciCanzoni.get(i).get(0));

                tv.setText(dieciCanzoni.get(i-1).get(1) + "\n" + dieciCanzoni.get(i-1).get(2));

                new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.albumImage)).execute(dieciCanzoni.get(i-1).get(4));

                iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {       
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(dieciCanzoni.get(i-1).get(3)));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                FineRound();
            }
        }
    });
```

LOGCAT:

```
11-13 19:42:47.835: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Started 
11-13 19:43:17.915: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Stopped
11-13 19:43:17.935: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Reset
11-13 19:43:17.940: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:17.990: E/MediaPlayer(1981): Error (-38,0)
11-13 19:43:17.990: E/MediaPlayer(1981): stop called in state 4
11-13 19:43:17.995: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:17.995: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Stopped
11-13 19:43:18.235: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Reset
11-13 19:43:18.235: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:18.270: E/MediaPlayer(1981): Error (-38,0)
11-13 19:43:18.285: E/MediaPlayer(1981): stop called in state 4
11-13 19:43:18.285: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:18.295: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Stopped
11-13 19:43:18.450: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Reset
11-13 19:43:18.450: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:18.470: E/MediaPlayer(1981): Error (-38,0)
11-13 19:43:18.475: E/MediaPlayer(1981): stop called in state 4
11-13 19:43:18.475: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:18.475: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Stopped
11-13 19:43:18.690: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Reset
11-13 19:43:18.690: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:18.735: E/MediaPlayer(1981): Error (-38,0)
11-13 19:43:18.735: E/MediaPlayer(1981): stop called in state 4
11-13 19:43:18.740: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:18.740: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Stopped
11-13 19:43:19.105: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Reset
11-13 19:43:19.105: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:19.185: E/MediaPlayer(1981): Error (-38,0)
11-13 19:43:19.185: E/MediaPlayer(1981): stop called in state 4
11-13 19:43:19.190: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:19.190: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Stopped
11-13 19:43:19.680: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Reset
11-13 19:43:19.680: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:19.780: E/MediaPlayer(1981): Error (-38,0)
11-13 19:43:19.800: E/MediaPlayer(1981): stop called in state 4
11-13 19:43:19.800: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:19.800: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Stopped
11-13 19:43:20.010: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Reset
11-13 19:43:20.015: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:20.130: E/MediaPlayer(1981): Error (-38,0)
11-13 19:43:20.130: E/MediaPlayer(1981): stop called in state 4
11-13 19:43:20.135: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:20.135: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Stopped
11-13 19:43:20.330: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Reset
11-13 19:43:20.330: E/MediaPlayer(1981): error (-38, 0)
11-13 19:43:20.365: E/MediaPlayer(1981): Error (-38,0)
11-13 19:43:22.105: D/MPLAY(1981): MP Started
11-13 19:43:25.590: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1981): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
11-13 19:43:25.615: D/OpenGLRenderer(1981): Flushing caches (mode 0)
11-13 19:43:26.140: D/OpenGLRenderer(1981): Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i can always help. I had this error too my solution was to check the path AS ANDROID MEDIA PLAYER RECIEVES IT. So to do this paste this code:

```
Log.d("MediaPlayer Datasource" , "The datasource is: " + url);
```

Check if the url is good and CONTAINS an extension. Make sure it is not protected with an domain.

if every thing is all right and fine paste this code:

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mediaPlayer.start();

    }
});
```

I know you all ready have one, but maybe it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use 3GP video Files it will work properly...